# Representing Multiple Variables Measured at Multiple Independent Times

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I'm attempting to find a good storage/data representation in "R" for a data set with a large number of variables, each of which is measured independently for a number of years but at irregular intervals.  Usually, a proper subset of variables are measured at the same year.  A few years have only one variable measured and a few years have nearly all variables measured.  Otherwise the data is not very sparse, ie: all objects are measured.

Unless there is a better representation, I've given up on time series representation and resorted to appending the year to the name of the variable being measured.  Of course, that dramatically expands the number of redundant columns, hence sparsity, and is not very "tidy", nor does it permit easy exploration of time dependencies.

Is there a better representation of such data?

Comment: Sounds like a list of data frame objects might work.

Comment: You mean a list indexed by keys that are the year of the data frame containing the variables measured in that year?  e.g. `measurements[['1998']] <- dataframefor1998`?

Comment: Without a more detailed reproducible example, I cannot say for sure, but that does seem like the right syntax.